# Unable to get desired result with Promise in Dialogflow API V2 DB Call

Tags: mysql, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to connect to MySQL db, get the result and pass it on to the Agent to be displayed to the user. As DB Query is asynchronous i have used Promise to get a callback and send the response after parsing the data. I do get the response in logs but the function execution ends before that and it does not seem to wait for **then** call.

Here is the code :

```
var sqlQuery = '';
  var dbResults = '';
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = 
functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  var reply = '';


  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

    function getBalance(){

                sqlQuery = 'select * from master_balance where account_no = \'1234567\'';

                callDB().then((results) => {

                var balance_type = request.body.queryResult.parameters['balance_type'];
                if(balance_type == 'SMS'){
                    console.log('In SMS');
                    reply = 'You have '+ results[0].bal_sms +' SMS left in your account';
                }
                else if(balance_type == 'Voice'){
                    console.log('In Voice-- from DB--'+results[0].bal_call);
                    reply = 'Your Voice balance is $ '+results[0].bal_call;
                }
                else if(balance_type == 'Data'){
                    console.log('In Data');
                    reply = 'You have '+results[0].bal_data +' MB left in your account';
                }
                else{
                    console.log('In Ahh');
                    reply = 'Ahh, there seems to be some issue. Please wait';
                }
                agent.add(reply);
                 return 1;
                 }).catch((error) => {
                     console.log('in catch----'+error);

                    });
        return 1;
     }



  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('Query.Balance', getBalance);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

function callDB() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('-- In callDB--'+sqlQuery);
        try {
            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                socketPath: '/cloudsql/' + connectionName,
                user: dbUser,
                password: dbPass,
                database: dbName
            });
            connection.query(sqlQuery, function (error, results, fields) {
                if (!error) {

                    console.log('--In no error 2--'+results[0]);
                    resolve(results);

                } else {

                    let output = {'speech': 'Error. Query Failed.', 'displayText': 'Error. Query Failed.'};
                    console.log('--- in else----'+error);

                    reject(results);

                }
            });
            connection.end();

        } catch (err) {
            let results = {'speech': 'try-cacth block error', 'displayText': 'try-cacth block error'};
            console.log(results);
            reject(results);

        }

    }
    );
}
```

Please help me with what i might be doing wrong. Another thing is that I am a noob when it comes to Node JS.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, if you're using an async function, then your intent handler *must also* return a Promise. It isn't enough that you send the reply as part of the `then()` clause, you must also return the Promise that the `then()` is part of.

In your case, this looks fairly easy. In the `getBalance()` function, you would return then `callDB().then().catch()` result, which is a Promise. (`then()` and `catch() return a Promise)

```
return callDB().then((results) => {
  ....
```

Comment: Okie.. Thank you. I'll try that out and will update.